# How to find .NET Maui sqlite DB file

Tags: .net, sqlite, maui

I have a .NET Maui Blazor App and configured SQLite storage via Entity Framework Core:

`builder.UseSqlite($"Data Source=app.db")`

Everything is working fine. For debugging purposes, I want to access the SQLite database file from a database explorer. I found that the file is stored at this location, when I start the app in Debug mode for Windows target.

`c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\5A71F6B4-07D1-4042-BC1C-C1FD1963A030_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState\app.db`.

This is poor developer experience.
How can I "mount" the database file from outside a .NET Maui Blazor app or specify the file path on the debugging host machine so that it's not random?

Comment: Open it with any SQLite db tool?

Comment: How can I specify a file location that is not generated randomly? I had to search my whole file system to find this file.

Comment: Is this the doc you used to know about builder.UseSqlite: [Net Maui local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite)? In your app, find what value is returned for `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory`. Is that the directory that was used?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I saw it. However, `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` is not available for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the database location by providing an absolute path in the connection string:

```
options.UseSqlite("Data Source=C:\your\path\app.db");
```

Answer (score 4):

The generated randomly file folder is `{GUID}_{hash}` which is generated randomly.
If you want to specify the path that the db located and remove the randomly number, you can try to use below which is located in `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\`:

```
string dataSource = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "app.db");

builder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={dataSource}");
```

Or you can use absolute path located in `C:`as Dimi suggested,

```
builder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\app.db");
```

Comment: Thanks. Storing in `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\app.db` does NOT work. That's what I already tried. However, storing in `C:\app.db` works.

Comment: `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "app.db");` is NOT working. So I accepted Dimitri's answer.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you get an error? Which path do you get from `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "app.db");`